# Read file into array 

Tags: command-line, bash

How can I read file in shell script , then assign each line to an variable that i can use later  ,,,(am thinking in way to load an default setting from file)

i already try :

```
process (){

}

FILE=''
read -p "Please enter name of default file : " FILE

if [ ! -f $FILE  ]; then

    echo "$FILE : does not exists "
    exit 1
elif [ ! -r $FILE  ]; then

    echo "$FILE : can not read "
fi

exec 0<"$FILE"
n=0
while read -r line
do
   (assign each line to an variable) 
done
```

Comment: any way (concept) that to load an default parameter that user saved in (file) , would be accepted :)

Comment: Using `. /path/to/config` is the best approach for setting defaults, but if you need to set lines of a file to an array variable (as your question title suggests), bash 4.0 has new builtin commands called `readarray` and `mapfile`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For configuration purposes it's probably easiest to define the parameters in the configuration file in bash syntax and later source it using `. /path/to/config`.

Example *default.cfg*:

```
parameter_a=100
parameter_b=200
parameter_c="Hello world"
```

Example *script.sh*:

```
#!/bin/bash

# source the default configuration
. /path/to/default.cfg

echo $parameter_a
echo $parameter_b
echo "$parameter_c"

...
```

---

If you don't like that approach you can also read the lines into an array:

```
while read line
do
    array+=("$line")
done < some_file
```

To access the items you would then use `${array[index]}`, e.g.:

```
for ((i=0; i < ${#array[*]}; i++))
do
    echo "${array[i]}"
done
```

(Where `${#array[*]}` is the size of the array.)

Read more about arrays in bash [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html).

Comment: I'd use `array+=("$line")` rather than `array[${#array[*]}]="$line"`, or if one needs to support bash older than v3.1, `array[i++]=$line` (where you make sure to set `i=0` before the loop of course).

Comment: I too recommend the source-approach btw. Though I'd use lowercase variable names rather than all uppercase... to avoid overwriting environment variables or internal shell variables.

Comment: @geirha: Thanks (once again) for your comments! Didn't know about the +=() syntax, which is definitely easier to read (and write).

Comment: You need to use `IFS= read -r` to avoid leading tabs/spaces being removed. Compare `printf "\thello\n  world\n" | while read -r line; do echo "$line"; done` and `printf "\thello\n  world\n" | while IFS read -r line; do echo "$line"; done `

Answer (score 0):

```
c=0 # counter
# read whole file in loop
while read line
do
  textArray[$c]=$line # store line
  c=$(expr $c + 1) # increase counter by 1
done < $FILE
# get length of array
len=$(expr $c - 1 )

# use for loop to reverse the array
for (( i=$len; i>=0; i-- ));
do
  echo ${textArray[$i]}
done
```

Comment: Don't use expr in bash, bash can do everything expr can, and better. The first "if" there makes no sense, you are not checking if a file exists... Lastly, quote all parameter expansions; `"$foo"`, not `$foo`. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments